# IP camera using a USB 3G Modem using same IP address on every boot

Tags: raspberry-pi, 3g, ip-camera, motion

I am looking to build a video monitoring system using raspberry pi. I used the motion software, and it worked well with ethernet.

Now, I am want to get it working with a 3G USB dongle. I am using a ZTE MF70 3G modem.

The problem is that with a 3G dongle, the IP address keeps on changing. How can I overcome this problem ? Is there a software or something to do so. I want the camera to always use the same IP address and port.

I want to view the live stream from anywhere in the world.

Or is there anything other than motion that I can use ??

Please help.

Comment: Services like [No-IP](http://www.noip.com), [DynDNS](http://dyn.com/dns/) (some alternatives you can find [here](http://lifehacker.com/the-best-free-alternatives-to-dyndns-1561556205)) can help you. But I don't know if there is smtg for raspberry.

Answer (score 0):

You need an internet connection with a Static IP. The default with most ISP's is dynamic IP i.e every time you connect to internet you get a new IP. Some ISP's charge extra for a static IP. You need to check if you have this option available.

Comment: If I understood the question correctly, he's try to connect a IP Camera internally, so static IP from the ISP won't work here.

Comment: he is using a 3G dongle connected to the raspberry pi. I don't see the reason why static IP (if available) wont work in this case.

Comment: I think I can use dynamicdns, right instead of a static IP ??